# How do I put a TCP send button in a loop in Java?

Tags: java, android, loops, tcp

I am attempting to create an application which has a edit text view and a button. This button will send whatever is in the edit text through a TCP connection to the server.

I have accomplished the sending of the edit text, but after I click the button once, the application crashes. How can I put this into a loop so I can send multiple messages? Here is my source

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //Handler h;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText eText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
        final TextView tView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pagetext);
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonGo);
                button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        try {
                            Socket s = new Socket("192.168.0.117", 4447);
                            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                            final BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
                            //send output msg
                            String outMsg = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.address)).getText().toString().trim();
                            out.write(outMsg);
                            out.flush();
                            Log.i("TcpClient", "sent: " + outMsg);
                        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                            tView.setText(e.toString());
                            Log.v("Tcp",e.toString());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            tView.setText(e.toString());
                            Log.v("Tcp",e.toString());
                        }catch (Exception e) {
                            tView.setText(e.toString());

                        } 
                    }
                }); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` (or some similar name)? Post your LogCat stack trace. And if it is, use a Thread/Runnable/AsyncTask for your network stuff, app won't crash and it's more efficient.

Comment: Its because you are doing it in the UI thread. Do this task in an asyntask or a separte thread.

Comment: Can you explain to me how to do this? Or point me in the right direction? Sorry, I am relatively new to Java programming and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You should also log `Exception`, and log the exceptions *before* you call setText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished this by using two different buttons. A connection button, and a send message button. I think when the server attempted to recreate the socket, the TCP connection broke and the server caught an exception and starting freaking out. Here is the new code.

```
            bConnect.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                        Socket s = new Socket("192.168.0.117", 4447);
                        out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        tView.setText(e.toString());
                        Log.v("Tcp",e.toString());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        tView.setText(e.toString());
                        Log.v("Tcp",e.toString());
                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        tView.setText(e.toString());

                    } 
                }
            });

            bSend.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                        String outMsg = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.address)).getText().toString().trim();
                        out.write(outMsg);
                        out.flush();
                        Log.i("TcpClient", "sent: " + outMsg);  
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    finally{

                    }
                    }


                });
```